# is there any performance benefit to using bulk_update as compared to just update in django for a same value update?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have the following piece of code

```
Subscription.objects.filter(id__in=[subscription.id for subscription in subscriptions]).update(renewal_notification_sent=True)
```

but I'm wondering if something like

```
updatable_subscriptions = []
subs = Subscription.objects.filter(id__in=[subscription.id for subscription in subscriptions])
for sub in subs:
    sub.renewal_notification_sent = True

updatable_subscriptions.append(
    subs
)

# then
Subscription.objects.bulk_update(updatable_subscriptions, ["renewal_notification_sent"])
```

would have any performance benefit. Does calling `filter` followed by `update` make 2 database queries?

Comment: I don't believe there's any benefit to using bulk_update like this. `filter().update()` gets turned into a single `UPDATE` statement. Can't beat that for speed.

Comment: If we need `subcriptions` instance after update, then use `bulk_update`. If not need, use `.update()`, it ony will generate 1 query and faster then bulk_update.

Comment: `subscription.id for subscription in subscriptions`: better way using `subscription_queryset.values_list("id", flat=True)`. It will generate a subquery instead of loop a list.

Comment: `bulk_update` will be better if `update_values` are different for different `ids`

Answer (score -2):

filter followed by update make 2 queries.
About performance, bulk_update does an sql update with case while update does a simple update behind the scenes, for bigger updates it's better use bulk_update.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).